# Pass QTreeView to qml window

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtreeview

I would like to display a QTreeView object created in c++ in my qml window. What is the best way to archive it ?

I tried to register QTreeView as a custom qml type but it does an error at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

are you using QML or widgets? There is a treeview component in QML.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as an actual answer but rather a comment, so formulate the answer better than post it :D

Comment: QTreeView and TreeView are two differents components. I want to display my c++ QTreeView and not creating a TreeView from Qt.Quick

Comment: You can do this by wrapping QTreeView object inside QQuickPaintedItem and resigter in qml. However, passing mouse events from QQuickPaintedItem back to QTreeView is quite problematic.